# influxdb2 and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, influxdb, nginx-reverse-proxy, influxdb-2

I have installed influxdb2 from their website and setup nginx according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx?domains.0.server.wwwSubdomain=true&domains.0.php.php=false&domains.0.reverseProxy.reverseProxy=true&domains.0.reverseProxy.path=%2Finfluxdb&domains.0.reverseProxy.proxyPass=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8086&domains.0.routing.index=index.html&domains.0.routing.fallbackHtml=true) amazing guide from digitalocean. I am trying to set a reverse proxy in order to query and post data to the db. I have my own URL and have set A records and a wildcard. I can access https:[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and mydomain.com .

problem 1.
when I run influxd I get the following error:

```
Error: listen tcp :8086: bind: address already in use
```

If I stop the service with `sudo systemctl stop influxdb`, I can then start the db. I cannot access it though...

problem 2.
the proxy is not working. Do you have any idea why?
My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf:

```
# reverse proxy
location /infuxdb {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8086;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    include               nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
}
```

and the contents of /etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf:

```
proxy_http_version                 1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

# Proxy SSL
proxy_ssl_server_name              on;
# Proxy headers
proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection        $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Forwarded         $proxy_add_forwarded;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

# Proxy timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
proxy_read_timeout                 60s;
```